# Nginx regular expression fails

Tags: regex, nginx

**When I visit the http://example.com or http://example.com/index.html still goes to handleURL.html**

This is what I have

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/public;
    index index.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/error.log;

    rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]{4,8})$" /forward.php?shortcode=$1;
    rewrite "^/.{10,500}$" /handleURL.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I want to display different html file if the url has characters between 10,500.

Comment: I mean if I have anything after / if its between 10 - 500 characters then display handleURL.html.

Comment: I have tested the regex with http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/ its perfect but for some reason it doesn't work on server.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Nginx might not care but it looks like the regular expression should not be in quotes.</s>  Unless your going to use the entered string in your replacement url you don't need to capture it, so the parenthesis are unnecessary.

If you want to choose a different file for each string you can use the captured string in the replacement string. e.g. `rewrite "^/(.{10,500})$" /wiki/$1 last;` would match `example.com/agreatpage.html` and turn it into `example.com/wiki/agreatepage.html`

To simply redirect to another page based on length something like `rewrite "^/.{10,500}$" /Redirect.html last;` should work

References:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

**Edit:**
After further reading nginx is okay if the regular expression is enclosed in double quotes and you must do so if the expression contains { or }, otherwise the parser misinterprets these as opening a block and closing a block.

**Edit2:**
The only problem I see at the moment is:

```
rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]{4,8})$" /forward.php?shortcode=$1;
rewrite "^/.{10,500}$" /handleURL.html;
```

to the best of my knowledge should be:

```
rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]{4,8})$" /forward.php?shortcode=$1 last;
rewrite "^/.{10,500}$" /handleURL.html last;
```

Comment: I mean if I have anything after / if its between 10 - 500 characters then display handleURL.html. –

Comment: That is not how regex patterns work. Nor is that required by OP.

Comment: Sorry about that I guess I was a little foggy when I wrote the answer. Fixed.

Comment: @Ersin Demirtas did you try removing the quotes to see if it changed anything?  I'm guessing there is just some funny handling going on. When you don't do it exactly like nginx wants.

Comment: `rewrite ^/.{10,500}$ /handleURL.html last;`



__2014/09/07 21:57:25 [emerg] 3327#0: directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:18__

Comment: If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes. **I must use double quotes.**

Comment: I have updated the question with my full server configuration

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can fix this remove all the rewrites and add index.php and pass everything to index.php I ended up with the following configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/vhosts/example.com/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        log_format compression '$host - $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/access.log compression;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }       

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Thank you guys!